# Intersect automatically updating Shape_Area and Shape_Length in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, intersect, shape-area

I am making a model in ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Desktop 10.1.

I am using **Intersect** tool. I need to calculate the **Shape_Area** and **Shape_Length** of my polygons (Projected Coordinate System, EPSG: 5514, S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North).

I noticed that these values are automatically calculated and joined to attribute table when I run the Intersect tool.

Is that true for every Intersect run? Or do I need to add tools: **Add field** and **Calculate field** to be sure that my calculations of Area and Length are correct and updated after Intersection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SHAPE_LENGTH` and `SHAPE_AREA` fields are dynamic *geodatabase* fields.  These are automatically updated when you modify a feature.

You will be unable to use the Calculate Field tool to update these fields manually.

This is fairly easy to test/verify.  Here I have run the Intersect tool on two polygon layers (`poly1` and `poly2`) to produce `poly3`.  I have then created additional test fields in `poly3` and calculated geometry in these.  You will see the calculated geometry matches the automatically updated `SHAPE_LENGTH` and `SHAPE_AREA` fields.

[image]

**Note:** these are **not** dynamic in a shapefile, only in a geodatabase.  In a shapefile these are user fields that would need to be calculated if you want them up-to-date.

**Also Note:** The values may also be worthless if the Spatial Reference is based on a Geographic Coordinate System.

Comment: They may also be worthless (if the SpatialReference is based on a GCS)

Comment: I would add in, for shapefiles the shape length and shape area do not automatically update